# Pythonic Purity Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

You are looking for a ten-letter word.

*Perfection is displayed not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away.*

```
  1 matter = []; matter.append('857'); matter.append(str(wrench)[8:]);                      matter.append('38479')

  2 import math, sys, random, glob, pickle

  3 tool = int(matter[0]+matter[1]+matter[2])

  4 String gear == (duble(5/5)+math.pi[4])/3

  5 whilis(true):

  6     print(random.randnums())

  7     tol += 5++

  8     for bit in piece: print(chr(int(bit)))

  9 aluminum = [[str(turn)[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(str(turn)), 2)]       for turn in cycle]

  10 sprocket = [x for x in range(lower, 'a')]

  11 machine = []; machine.append('6');machine.append(str(tool)[2:4]);                      machine.append('2658283')

  12 wrench = math.floor(2.3)*11*13*math.isqrt(289)*67*(111**2+106**2)

  13 cycle = [wrench, tool, lever]

  14 if a|b: print(a||b)

  15 elsif: print(a&&b)

  16 _='_=%rrint (_%%_)';print (__)

  17 ferrum = math.lowerbound(523) + 612 + 3.0 + (5.0, 3, 3)

  18 pickle.dump('stock', 53)

  19 lever = int(machine[0]+machine[1]+machine[2])

  20 for piece in aluminum: 
 
  21     int cam = "five"

  22 switch(cam):

  23     case (cam == 5):

  24         print(5);;

  25     alse:

  26         solution = [&%"trgevqbsrireloebxrayvar"]
```

Comment: +1 for the use of a switch-case statement in Python!

Comment: The original quote is usually translated from the French as "Perfection is *achieved*..." by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Full Solution

```
1 matter = []; matter.append('857'); matter.append(str(wrench)[8:]);                      matter.append('38479')
2 import math, sys, random, glob, pickle
3 tool = int(matter[0]+matter[1]+matter[2])
4 String gear == (duble(5/5)+math.pi[4])/3
5 whilis(true):
6     print(random.randnums())
7     tol += 5++
8     for bit in piece: print(chr(int(bit)))
9 aluminum = [[str(turn)[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(str(turn)), 2)]       for turn in cycle]
10 sprocket = [x for x in range(lower, 'a')]
11 machine = []; machine.append('6');machine.append(str(tool)[2:4]);                      machine.append('2658283')
12 wrench = math.floor(2.3)*11*13*math.isqrt(289)*67*(111**2+106**2)
13 cycle = [wrench, tool, lever]
14 if a|b: print(a||b)
15 elsif: print(a&&b)
16 _='_=%rrint (_%%_)';print (__)
17 ferrum = math.lowerbound(523) + 612 + 3.0 + (5.0, 3, 3)
18 pickle.dump('stock', 53)
19 lever = int(machine[0]+machine[1]+machine[2])
20 for piece in aluminum: 
21     int cam = "five"
22 switch(cam):
23     case (cam == 5):
24         print(5);;
25     alse:
26         solution = [&%"trgevqbsrireloebxrayvar"]
```

The string in the last line…

> reads "getridofeverybrokenline" in rot13

If we do that we are left with:

> ```
> 1 matter = []; matter.append('857'); matter.append(str(wrench)[8:]);matter.append('38479')
> 2 import math, sys, random, glob, pickle
> 3 tool = int(matter[0]+matter[1]+matter[2])
> 8     for bit in piece: print(chr(int(bit)))
> 9 aluminum = [[str(turn)[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(str(turn)), 2)] for turn in cycle]
> 11 machine = []; machine.append('6');machine.append(str(tool)[2:4]); machine.append('2658283')
> 12 wrench = math.floor(2.3)1113*math.isqrt(289)67(1112+1062)
> 13 cycle = [wrench, tool, lever]
> 19 lever = int(machine[0]+machine[1]+machine[2])
> 20 for piece in aluminum:
> ```

These are syntactically valid, but they are out of order, we reorder the statements based on which statement uses the results of which other statements. Since it's python we put the import at the top:

> ```
> 2 import math, sys, random, glob, pickle
> ```

Then `wrench` doesn't depend on anything else so put that next:

> ```
> 12 wrench = math.floor(2.3)1113*math.isqrt(289)67(1112+1062)
> ```

`matter` depends only on `wrench` so it's next:

> ```
> 1 matter = []; matter.append('857'); matter.append(str(wrench)[8:]);matter.append('38479')
> ```

`tool` depends only on `matter`:

> ```
> 3 tool = int(matter[0]+matter[1]+matter[2])
> ```

`machine` depends on `tool`:

> ```
> 11 machine = []; machine.append('6');machine.append(str(tool)[2:4]); machine.append('2658283')
> ```

`lever` depends on `machine`:

> ```
> 19 lever = int(machine[0]+machine[1]+machine[2])
> ```

`cycle` depends on `wrench`, `tool`, `lever`:

> ```
> 13 cycle = [wrench, tool, lever]
> ```

`aluminum` depends on `cycle`:

> ```
> 9 aluminum = [[str(turn)[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(str(turn)), 2)] for turn in cycle]
> ```

Now the `for` loop can be put:

> ```
> 20 for piece in aluminum:
> 8     for bit in piece: print(chr(int(bit)))
> ```

Now run this code in the python shell:

> ```
> import math, sys, random, glob, pickle
> wrench = math.floor(2.3)1113*math.isqrt(289)67(1112+1062)
> matter = []; matter.append('857'); matter.append(str(wrench)[8:]);matter.append('38479')
> tool = int(matter[0]+matter[1]+matter[2])
> machine = []; machine.append('6');machine.append(str(tool)[2:4]); >!machine.append('2658283')
> lever = int(machine[0]+machine[1]+machine[2])
> cycle = [wrench, tool, lever]
> aluminum = [[str(turn)[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(str(turn)), 2)] for turn in cycle]
> for piece in aluminum:
>   for bit in piece: print(chr(int(bit)))
> ```

It prints:

> `LINENUMBERSARECHARS`

Take the line numbers:

> 2,12,1,3,11,19,13,9,20,8 and those are BLACKSMITH in the alphabet

Comment: We do have spoiler syntax here - I've edited your post to add it in, and fixed a typo.

Comment: Also, could you add a more detailed explanation? Right now it's pretty unclear what you mean.

Comment: I cant figure out how to get both spoiler text and preformatted text - the SO formatting system is weird

Comment: [how to put spoilers in code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105735/how-can-i-put-a-whole-code-block-in-spoiler-text)